# Ajax call redirects to php file instead of calling another php file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

so on submit of my form class `.login` this triggers an `ajax` call to `login.php` Inside of `login.php` there is a call to `welcome.php` to ensure that the encrypted password matches that in the database and that the user name entered exists in the database. It would also be helpful to mention my `ajax` call is succeeding in it's attempts to run, but no redirection to my `welcome.php` occurs. So, my question to you all, is am I going about this in the correct manor?

```js
$('.login').on('submit', function(){

       // serialize the form
       var formData = $(this).serialize();
       $.ajax({
           type        : 'POST',
           url         : 'login.php',
           data        : formData,

           success: function() {
             alert("Success");
           },
            error: function(xhr) {
             alert("fail");
           }
       })
       .done(function (data) {
          
       })
       .fail(function (error) {
           console.log(data);
       });
       return false;
 });
```

```css
<html>
<body>
<?php
require 'connect.php';
if((isset($_POST['user-login']) && !empty($_POST['user-login']))||
   (isset($_POST['pass-login']) && !empty($_POST['pass-login']))){

  $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name FROM test_table WHERE name=?;');


  $passLogin = $_POST['pass-login'];
  $nameLogin = $_POST['user-login'];
  
  $sth->execute(Array($nameLogin));

if(password_verify($passLogin, $hashed_password) &&  $sth->rowCount() > 0) {
    header("Location:welcome.php");
    exit;
  }
}
else{
  echo 'error';
}
?>
</body>
</html>

*****************************************************************
<html>
<body>
  <?php
  echo 'welcome';
  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">

<form class = "login">
      <label for="user-login">Username</label>
      <input id="user-login" name="user-login"></br>
      <label for="pass-login">Password</label>
      <input id="pass-login" name="pass-login"></br>
      <input type="submit" name= "submit" value="submit" id = "submit">
      <a id = "register-a">Register Now</a>
    </form>
```

Comment: Where do you think `$hashed_password` is going to magically appear from? You must FETCH data from an executed statement in order to see it

Comment: An ajax call doesn't make the page redirect, the entire point is to make requests "behind the scenes", without redirects.

Comment: So the reason I have ajax call is because I my initial design is to not leave the page, it got me wondering if this was possible, so I tried to turn it into a redirect.

Comment: @RiggsFolly well said, I didn't even see I forgot to query for that.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to redirect your page using javascript. An Ajax request cannot redirect the users browser from server side. I recommend if your login is successful, pass back a success flag for your ajax `success()` function to handle then have THAT do the redirect using `window.location.href`.

Just a heads up in case you weren't aware, your script will always return successful. Even if you `echo 'error';`. You'd need to actually form a failing HTTP status code for the error function to execute, or alternatively have an error in your code!

Comment: Just to add, when your ajax request is made, the php script is running a completely different process to say your page load. The context is separated from the page itself and so you cannot perform any actions that you expect to change the behaviour on the page, unless you return the data to JS and have JS handle everything :)

Answer (score -1):

The point of Ajax is to make an HTTP request without leaving the current page. The browser doesn't appear to redirect because the results are returned to the Ajax handler which does nothing with them (your `done` function is empty).

Your goal appears to be to make an HTTP request and then display the Welcome page.

You should not use Ajax. Just use a regular form submission.

If there is a problem with the submitted data (and most of the time there will not be, so it isn't worth applying Ajax for that case) then redisplay the form.

Answer (score -1):

This is possible, however you are never reaching the redirect call because 
`$hashed_password` in the if statement is not defined.

This will throw an error message but you will need to use a tool like chrome inspector > network > login.php to see the response.

Hope this helps debug in the future :)